# How can the CrossValidated Stack Exchange site be added to the re-direct listing?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

For this recent question (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129539/goodness-of-fit-for-two-histograms) it seems that CrossValidated would be a much more appropriate site than the Mathematics or Meta Mathematics Stack Exchange sites to transfer the question (as the question currently does not involve Mathematica software).

Can CrossValidated be added to the list as this is likely to occur frequently in the future?  (And in my short tenure around here it would have been appropriate many times in the past.)

Comment: This is addressed here in my answer (although the target site is different): http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1095/5 You probably can't see the current migration stats, but there has been only 1 migration to CV in the past 90 days, so this hasn't been occurring frequently enough to warrant a direct migration path. For such cases, you can always flag to have it migrated by a moderator (Verbeia's answer) :)

Comment: @m_goldberg.  I agree.  It is a duplicate.  Shoulda searched a bit more.